# Запятая перед «как» нужна?

Tags: обороты-с-как

«Город выглядит как с картинки». Не ставить запятую перед «как»? Думаю, можно заменить – «красиво выглядит».

Comment: ...Как с картины сошедший, — и серьёзней, и с запятой без вариантов.

Comment: А почему нельзя заменить?

Comment: Красиво? Выглядит красиво, а так не очень? Тогда уж — «город красив».

Comment: а как часть составного сказуемого?

Comment: https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/tipy-sostavnogo-skazuemogo

Comment: Я бы написала так: Город – как с картинки! Или так: Город – как с картинки срисованный! Сомнительная сочетаемость – выглядеть (как) с картинки просматривается даже через союз КАК Обычно встречаются выражения: выглядит как принцесса (И.п.);  красивый, как с картинки, офицер; итальянец был как с картинки; выглядеть как на картинке.

Answer (score 3):

*Выглядит как с картинки* - сказуемое. Отлично смотрится город. Никакой запятой.

[Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК в пяти случаях:](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

> 1. Если оборот с союзом КАК в предложении выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия, например: Тропинка извивалась как
>    змея. В таких случаях оборот с КАК можно заменить наречием
>    (ПО-ЗМЕИНОМУ) или существительным в творительном падеже (ЗМЕЕЙ). К
>    сожалению, не всегда обстоятельства образа действия можно с полной
>    уверенностью отличить от обстоятельств сравнения.
> 2. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав фразеологизма, например: Во время обеда она сидела как на иголках;
> 3. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла, например: Она
>    держится как хозяйка;
> 4. Если союз КАК стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым (без этого союза там требовалось бы поставить тире), например: Озеро как зеркало;
> 5. Если сравнительному обороту предшествует отрицание НЕ или частицы СОВСЕМ, СОВЕРШЕННО, ПОЧТИ, ВРОДЕ, ТОЧЬ-В-ТОЧЬ, ИМЕННО, ПРОСТО,
>    например: Они все делают не как соседи или Волосы у нее вьются
>    точь-в-точь как у матери.